# Couchdb and proxy authentication

Tags: couchdb, proxy-authentication

I have been using couchdb for a long time and we authenticate through cookies auth. Now we would like to start testing proxy authentication but I don't quite understand how it works.

I already have it activated including the value "chttpd_auth, proxy_authentication_handler" in the section "chttpd / authentication_handlers:" but how do I indicate that the token x is for the user y?

I can't understand how it works

I hope someone can help me with an example. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `proxy_authentication`, you are doing authentication somewhere else. That
somewhere else is a proxy, or to be more specific a reverse proxy.

For example, if you're just using a single user and using nginx as a proxy to
`couchdb`, you set the required headers before request is passed to `couchdb`
like:

```
location / {
    # pass to couchdb
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5984;

    # ... other configurations.

    # authentication header
    proxy_set_header    X-Auth-CouchDB-UserName 'someone';
    proxy_set_header    X-Auth-CouchDB-Roles    '_admin,staff';
    proxy_set_header    X-Auth-CouchDB-Token    'auth-token';
}
```

Couchdb will accept request with given `username` and `roles`. `X-Auth-CouchDB-Token` should be a hex encoded `hmac` of `X-Auth-CouchDB-UserName` using `secret` in `couch_httpd_auth` section in your configuration. It is not required unless `proxy_use_secret` is `true`, which is not the case by default (although it should it should be used in production).

In practice, you will need to create a proxy server that validates `username`
(maybe with password). Only after the user is valid the request will be passed
to couchdb with those headers attached.

Comment: I see but what is token header value? Is there any way to calculate?

Comment: Added explanation about the token.

Comment: Oh! I didn’t find this in doc... I will try .. now all have sense 

Comment: It's in the doc. it's just scattered all over the place. ;)

Comment: Hi again, I get it. Only add, for me and other than me lost with this subject, **hmac-sha1**. First I was trying with hmac-sha256 and doesn't work. For testing we can generate in https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html. Thanks folks